# Reference method name in string

Tags: ruby, methods

One can do this:

```
s="puts"
send(s,"Hello World!")
# => Hello World!
```

How can one check if `s` is a method? If it was:

```
s="nomethod"
```

`send(s,arg)` will fail.

This would be cool:

`ismethod? s`

P.S. I am porting something from PHP, which relies on:

```
if (function_exists($s)) 
    ...
```

If only Ruby had something so simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
respond_to?(method_name)
```

It should return true if the current object (self) responds to a method by that name.  You can use `respond_to?` on any Ruby object.

http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F

Comment: `respond_to?(s)` results in `false`, as does (obviously) `resond_to?("puts")`. What's odd is that `respond_to?(puts)` results in `TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string` (`respond_to?(gak)` results in `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'gak'` which is expected)

Comment: oh, and thank you for your input, it's leading me in the right direction

Comment: (p.s. the TypeError above is probably because `puts` returns `nil`.)

Comment: Yeah, `respond_to?('puts')` is actually retuning nil for me in IRB, and I don't know why.  But `Kernel.respond_to?('puts')` returns true.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the answer. I did not know about `Kernel` module. Thank you.